# Get multiple individual DC voltage sources from a single line

Tags: voltage, dc

If I connect 2 6V batteries or two individual sources serially the combined voltage should be the sum of the voltage of each battery (i.e. 12V). Is it possible to get 12 volts from a single source or battery of 6 volts? Actually I have to power my DSL router of (12v-700mA) from my laptop's USB port (5volts).

Schematic diagram will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your laptop's USB port supplies only 500mA. So, that is impossible with the USB port. Because even in the ideal conditions, output power cannot be higher than input power. In your case:

Your output power: 12*0.7= 8.4 Watts

Your input power: 5*0.5(max) = 2.5 Watts

With a 95% efficiency of the converter, you need at least an ~8.9 Watt input power.

However, if you have a higher current source with 5V, you can do it. And the way to convert a voltage by increasing it to a higher voltage is done by a "[boost converter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_converter)"*.

A boost converter is a switch-mode power supply and it can be fairly easy to build one by using a [Simple Switcher](http://www.ti.com/ww/en/simple_switcher_dc_dc_converters/index.html) from National Semiconductor.

[Here](http://www.national.com/appinfo/webench/scripts/SD2.cgi?ID=110863) is a design I selected using WEBENCH. It uses LM2585 at 100KHz. So it will be fairly easy for you to make it work. Because higher the frequency, harder it gets to build it.

**Generally, I think. Correct me here if I'm wrong, guys.*

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: This may not be he, but the Phantom-Coward goes about downvoting some eminently sensible stuff and never explaining why.

Comment: lol, actually he/she down voted because I first wrote the first three sentences and then published the answer, immediately after that, I started adding more and published again. in the mean time, he/she down voted.

Comment: Your first 3 sentences are in fact reasonably accurate. Recent changes to the USB powering standards allow more than 500 mA from some ports. So far they are not usual.

Comment: The only objection I can see is your completely pointless and content free first sentence.  What exactly is *"OK, here is the thing."* supposed to convey?  However, your technical content is sound and your stupid first sentence doesn't merit a downvote in my opinion.  I have upvoted to offset the undeserved downvote.  I think I may edit out your first sentence.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I agree that there is no reason for a downvote here, but you should also be aware that downvotes and upvotes are not equal... 1 downvote takes away 2 rep from the post owner while 1 upvote gives 10 rep to the post owner... So for this answer, abdullah has gained 58 rep. Although this answer is good, it is not nearly as good as some answer that get almost no upvotes. Basically what I am trying to say is, we shouldn't be upvoting just to offset one persons down vote.

Comment: Also, Abdullah has pointed out that he first posted a very short answer, which is when the downvote took place. Now that the answer has been edited the downvoter can come back and remove their down vote, resulting in an "offset up vote" becoming just a normal up vote. In fact, that has happened here.

Comment: @Kellenjb: I understand about up and down votes not being equal in rep.  However, they are equal in appearance and sort order between answers, which are the most important issues.  While this answer isn't "great" in that is should be worth 68 rep, I don't mind giving him extra 10 rep from me for being abused by the Phantom Coward.  Even the first few sentences aren't wrong.  They don't make a great answer and probably don't deserve a upvote, but certainly not a downvote either.

Comment: Well I am still a learner and trying my best to help anyone I can. Of course I don't deserve 8 up votes for this answer. In the first sentence, I didn't mean to be or do something, I just wrote what I thought that time and wanted to be more friendly than being freezing cold.